# Is this a PRF? Fk(x) = G(k⊕x) where G is a PRG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

This is not homework, but a random thought.

Let $G(x)$ be a PRG.
We define the following function:
$$F_k(x) = G(k\oplus x)$$

My intuition is that it shouldn't be a PRF but I couldn't come with an example yet.

I tried to build a reduction from identifying G to identifying F but I'm not certain how you can simulate an oracle call when all you have is some string.

Comment: This allows you to construct related PRG inputs which probably is exploitable for a suitable PRG definition.

Comment: Consider the counter-example in your [recent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/77594/is-this-a-prg-gx-gx-%e2%8a%95-x-0lx-x) question.

Comment: One possible proof technique here might be to assume that $G$ is not some arbitrary PRG, but one that you opportunistically construct to make it easily exploitable in the $F$ construction. I.e., don't try to write a proof that attacks *any* choice of $G$, but rather figure out what properties $G$ could have that don't disqualify it as a PRG but are exploitable when used as a component in $F$. And one way to construct a suitable $G$ might be to assume you're given an arbitrary PRG $G'$ and define some construction that delegates to it but makes some changes to its input or output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given some PRG $G : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^m$ with $m > n+1$, define $G' : \{0,1\}^{n+1} \to \{0,1\}^m$ like this:

$$
\begin{align}
G'(0\|x) & = G(x) \\
G'(1\|x) & = G(x) 
\end{align}
$$

---

**Lemma:** If $G$ is a PRG, so is $G'$.

**Proof:** Let $s \in \{0,1\}^{n+1}$ be a randomly chosen seed, and let $s' \in \{0,1\}^{n}$ be its suffix (with the first bit of $s$ removed), which is also distributed uniformly at random. Since $G$ is a PRG, then $G(s')$ has a pseudorandom distribution. And since $G'(s) = G(s')$, so does $G'(s)$ have a pseudorandom distribution. So then, since $G'(s)$ is pseudorandom for random $s$, $G'$ is a PRG.

---

**Theorem:** $F_k(x) = G'(k \oplus x)$ is not a PRF.

**Proof:** Because of the definitions of $F$ and $G'$, we see that for all $k$ and $s$, $F_k(0\|s) = F_k(1\|s)$. Given oracle access to an $f$ that's either $F_k$ or a random function, we have the following distinguisher:

1. Pick an arbitrary $s$;
2. Query the oracle for $x_0 = f(0\|s)$;
3. Query the oracle for $x_1 = f(1\|s)$;
4. If $x_0 = x_1$, then output $1$, otherwise output $0$.

If $f$ is a random function, this outputs $1$ with probability $2^{-m}$.  But if $f$ is $F_k$, then it outputs $1$ with probability $1$.

---

So, there exists a choice of PRG for which your proposed construction is not a PRF.